# AlarmManager.setRepeating in android dose not work correctly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i wrote this code to repeatedly call a service any 60 second, but it calls that service any second, what is the problem guys?

```
 PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
 m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), (1000 * 60), service);
```

Comment: you need to pass the instance of `PendingIntent` instead of service

Comment: sorry, I'm dummy. I did not get you. What I must do?

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: guys!! i run it on HUAWEI g610 with android 4.2 and happen this problem. when i run it on emulator everything goes correct. whyyyyy?